# Unable to get machine type information for machine type n1-standard-2 in zone us-central-c because of insufficient permissions - Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-iam

I am not sure what I am missing but somehow I am not able to start the job and gets failed with insufficient permission:

[image]

Here is terraform code I run:

```
resource "google_dataflow_job" "poc-pubsub-stream" {
  project                 = local.project_id
  region                  = local.region
  zone                    = local.zone
  name                    = "poc-pubsub-to-cloud-storage"
  template_gcs_path       = "gs://dataflow-templates-us-central1/latest/Cloud_PubSub_to_GCS_Text"
  temp_gcs_location       = "gs://${module.poc-bucket.bucket.name}/tmp"
  enable_streaming_engine = true
  on_delete               = "cancel"
  service_account_email   = google_service_account.poc-stream-sa.email

  parameters = {
    inputTopic           = google_pubsub_topic.poc-topic.id
    outputDirectory      = "gs://${module.poc-bucket.bucket.name}/"
    outputFilenamePrefix = "poc-"
    outputFilenameSuffix = ".txt"
  }

  labels = {
    pipeline = "poc-stream"
  }

  depends_on = [
    module.poc-bucket,
    google_pubsub_topic.poc-topic,
  ]
}
```

My SA permission that is used in the terraform code:

[image]

Any thoughts what I am missing?

Comment: Add roles/compute.viewer role to resolve your issue. Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#creating_jobs) for required permissions to create a Dataflow job. Let me know If it is resolved or not.

Comment: I added that scope but getting the same result

Comment: Hi @Askar, GCP support here. We'd like to take a look at your setup. [Can you raise a private thread in the issue tracker (referencing this question, as stated in the template) with the project ID?](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=491268&template=1161126&hl=en_GB&pli=1) After you've created the thread, please share here the issue ID so we can follow up. Note that issues in that component will only be accessible for you and GCP support.

Comment: Thank you @Vishal. I worked it out with Google Infrastructure team.

Comment: Hi @Askar, can you clarify if the issue was specific to the Terraform options only or was it due to the lack of `roles/compute.viewer` role in the service account also?

Comment: Hi @Askar, If you don't mind, can you run your Dataflow job again by removing the `roles/compute.viewer` role from your service account? I appreciate your effort for resolving the issue by working with the Google Infrastructure team and posting the answer. As per your question, the provided error seems to be related with the Service Account permission issue. But, the resolution was quite different. We may have to rephrase your question/answer for better understanding for future Stack Overflow visitors.

Answer (score 0):

The error describes being unable to get the machine type information because of insufficient permissions. To access the machine type information, add the [roles/compute.viewer](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.viewer) role to your service account.

> The roles/compute.viewer role, to access machine type information and view other settings.

Refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/access-control#creating_jobs) for more information about the required permissions to create a Dataflow job.

Comment: It did not help after adding it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my DataFlow job needed to provide these following options.  Per docs it was optional but in my case that needed to be defined.

```
...
  network                 = data.terraform_remote_state.dev.outputs.network.network_name
  subnetwork              = data.terraform_remote_state.dev.outputs.network.subnets["us-east4/us-east4-dev"].self_link
...
```